# How to run the email function?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

```
public function email($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('my.email@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
            // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                ':emails:task.twig',
                ['name' => $name]
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);

    return $this->render(':emails:task.twig');
}
```

I have just copied that code from https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html and changed few things.

I would like to run that function but what I don't understand is, what is the second parameter? I am using this function in my service class.

Comment: if you mean \Swift_Mailer its service from DI container. You have to get it from constructor with DI for example. Just ask for \Swift_Mailer and put instance as second parameter.

Comment: the code you linked looks like its located inside a controller. In a service you would most likely add the mailer to your constructor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// class or controller registered in DI container
class InvoiceMailer
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    private function email($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('my.email@example.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                    ':emails:task.twig',
                    ['name' => $name]
                ),
                'text/html'
            );

         $mailer->send($message);
    }

    public function SendEmail($name)
    {
        $this->email($name, $this->mailer);
    }
}
```

[DI using in symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#autowiring-by-default-use-type-hint-instead-of-service-id)